# Не подключается к базе данных через домен

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Всем привет! У меня такая проблема вышло при соединении к БД:

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  user: 'mysql_user',
  password: '12121212',
  host: 'mydomain.com',
  database: 'mysql_database'
})

connection.execute('SELECT 1+? as test1', [10], (err, rows) => {
    console.log(rows)
    console.log(err)
});
```

При соединении библиотека автоматический определяет IP адрес и не ставит домен. То есть если написать localhost, то подключает как 127.0.0.1. А в моем хостинге разрешено только через домен. Пожалуйста помогите как решить проблему?

Вот такая ошибка:

```
Access denied for user 'mysql_user'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: «А в моем хостинге разрешено только через домен» — это как?

Comment: Через IP адрес (root@127.0.0.1) не подключается. Только через доменное имя localhost. То есть root@localhost

Comment: Решил вопрос) Подключил через сокеты. Как закрыть вопрос?